# How to make a get request using URL in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using React as my front end and express for backend.

As far as I know if I declare get methods in my express as follows:-

```
app.get('/addBill',(req,res)=>{     //  --first method
    res.render("addBill");  
});

app.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {  // --second method
    res.render("EditBill"); 
});
```

If I write something like **localhost:3000/addBill** in the URL then I end up hitting **first method**, and if I write **localhost:3000/edit/1** in the URL then I end up hitting **second method** and get the required page if I am not using React and using it with **ejs**. Is the same possible in React?

What I want to do in React is if I write in my URL **localhost:3000/addBill** then I get to **/addBill** method and if I write **localhost:3000/edit/1** then I get to **/editBill** method and perform some action depending on the method I reached.

I am unable to use the URL for this and the only way I can do it right now is using fetch API, which allows for only one call independent of whatever is in URL. I am making a call like below:-

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/add")//---- or using edit in place of add,basically how to make this call dynamic and/or URL dependent?
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <p>{!data ? "Loading...": data}</p>
      <BillTable />
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

What changes are needed and where to allow me to make calls depending upon what I write in the URL?

Comment: Both your backend and frontend server are on port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the path from the url

```
const path = window.location.href.slice(window.location.origin.length)
```

if the current url is  localhost:3000/addBill , the path will be /addBill

if the current url is  localhost:3000/edit/1 , the path will be /edit/1

and instead of fetch("/add") use fetch(path)